# How to type Cyrillique TeX source code?

Tags: languages, editors, input-encodings

I compose in Russian (Cyrillique).

I've just dowloaded TexShop 3.48. When opened, all my old `.tex` files with Russian fonts, the text in main TexShop window is no more correct (encoding `pb`). The composition works well, the output PDF file is well in Russian. But I can't visualise the Cyrillique source-code.

Could you please indicate how I can write in Russian (source code)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001)

Comment: Were the old files created on the Mac too?  Do you know how they were encoded? (I'm not sure what you mean by `pb` as an encoding.)

Comment: OK, I just need to change the encoding at Opening (lad files were in Windows Cyrillique, the new ones are in Maccyr). Everything OK now

Comment: You might want to look at [TeXShop doesn't remember file encoding](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46199/2693).