# XeLaTeX produces gibberish with Devanagari document in TeXShop

Tags: xetex, texshop

I was able to process `devanagari`-documents into PDF successfully a couple of years ago on my Mac. I tried processing a simple document with `xelatex` but it doesn't work. My document is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Nakula}
नमस्ते रुद्र मन्यवे
\end{document}
```

Below is an image of all the fonts that are installed on my Mac (running Sierra 10.12.1)

[image]

Here's log file displayed in TeXshop's console:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Untitled.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3unicode-data.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-patches.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmss.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(./Untitled.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
[1] (./Untitled.aux) )
Output written on Untitled.pdf (1 page).
SyncTeX written on Untitled.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on Untitled.log.
```

I also tried setting the font type to "Devanagari MT" but that didn't work either.

**Update:**

I downloaded and installed *texlive-2016* and re-ran my file through `xelatex`. Now it produces a meaningful error Font **'Nakula' does not contain script 'Devanagari'.**

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Untitled.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmss.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(./Untitled.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "script-not-exist"
* 
* Font 'Nakula' does not contain script 'Devanagari'.
*************************************************
[1] (./Untitled.aux) )
Output written on Untitled.pdf (1 page).
SyncTeX written on Untitled.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on Untitled.log.
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Somehow it doesn't make sense that the output contains six question marks: the input has 19 Unicode codepoints (two of them spaces) or 8 glyphs (Devanagari aksharas) (plus two spaces). Where does 6 come from: are you sure you're looking at the correct output file? :-) (For example, "नमस्ते" has exactly 6 Unicode codepoints…).

Comment: Yes it does. Please see https://www.dropbox.com/s/d1fmeoitquxnj04/zoom_0.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Try clicking on "Trash Aux Files" to delete the aux files; also remove the `\expandafter` line (and/or hit Enter at the prompt in TeXShop's console to make the compilation complete).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help :=) https://www.dropbox.com/s/d1fmeoitquxnj04/after-trashing-aux.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Arrgghh. I found the solution. TexShop was converting my file to plain-text. When I `cat` the file, I saw a bunch of ??? instead of devanagari letters. I added a line at the top of my file (as per http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46199/texshop-doesnt-remember-file-encoding) and now I finally see devanagari in my pdf! Thanks @ShreevatsaR and all others for your help

Comment: Ouch. Can you post that as an answer and "accept" it? Would help future people with the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that TeXShop apparently defaults to saving documents as `latin1`, rather than `utf-8` as a modern editor would.

Although adding the `!TS` line in every document is an option, the best thing to do is to alter the default encoding for files in TeXShop's preferences so that `utf-8` is used by default. A `!TS` line can then be used to override this in the unlikely event that it is ever necessary.

This happened to one of my students a couple of weeks ago and I was astonished that TeXShop does not default to `utf-8`. But it certainly doesn't - this was a brand new install and there it was: `latin1` encoding for all documents as default.

Comment: I did as you suggested and agree that it is more efficient than applying a workaround to every `.tex` file. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The real problem was with TexShop. It saved my file as ASCII and not unicode:

```
$ file zz.tex 
zz.tex: LaTeX 2e document text, ASCII text

$ cat zz.tex 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontscript{Devanagari}{deva}
\setmainfont{Devanagari MT}

\begin{document}

?????? ????? ??????
\end{document}
```

This gave me a hint that the file-type was incorrect. Following [TeXShop doesn't remember file encoding](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46199/texshop-doesnt-remember-file-encoding), I added the following as the first line of my `.tex` file:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

and everything worked just fine.

```
$ file zz.tex 
zz.tex: LaTeX 2e document text, UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Comment: This will work, but please see [my answer below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345161/). This happened to one of my students a couple of weeks ago and I was astonished that TeXShop does not default to this. But it certainly doesn't - this was a brand new install and there it was: `latin1` encoding for all documents as default.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

The following document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Path=./,Extension=.ttf,Script=Devanagari]{nakula}

\begin{document}

नमस्ते रुद्र मन्यवे

\expandafter\show\the\font

\end{document}
```

halts XeLaTeX (as expected) and displays the information

```
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "script-not-exist"
* 
* Font 'nakula' does not contain script 'Devanagari'.
*************************************************
(./nak.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
> \EU1/nakula(0)/m/n/10=select font "[./nakula.ttf]/OT:script=deva;language=DFL
T;mapping=tex-text;".
<inserted text> \EU1/nakula(0)/m/n/10 

l.9 \expandafter\show\the\font
```

Thus you can see that the warning message is spurious, which seems to be a small bug in `fontspec`. Indeed, if I do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontscript{Devanagari}{deva}

\setmainfont[Path=./,Extension=.ttf,Script=Devanagari]{nakula}

\begin{document}

नमस्ते रुद्र मन्यवे

\expandafter\show\the\font

\end{document}
```

no warning is issued and the font information is exactly the same. As you can see, the script *is* correctly loaded.

The output on my system is

[image]

I can't read the Devanagari script, so I can't judge whether it's correct or not. However, other software shows

[image]

Comment: Errors after applying changes that you suggested:
kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `[./Nakula.ttf]/OT', contains '['

./Untitled.tex:5: fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! The font "Nakula" cannot be found.
l.5 .../,Extension=.ttf,Script=Devanagari]{Nakula}                   
kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `[./Nakula.ttf]/OT', contains '['
./Untitled.tex:5: Font EU1/Nakula(0)/m/n/10=[./Nakula.ttf]/OT:mapping=tex-text;
 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.
<to be read again> relax 
l.5 .../,Extension=.ttf,Script=Devanagari]{Nakula}

Comment: Your output looks perfect. Is there a way to get the correct names of all fonts installed on my system?

Comment: Try with `\setmainfont{Nakula}` -- you probably don't have Nakula in your current folder.

Comment: No luck even after making the change suggested by Ulrike. All the additional fonts (Chandas, Charis SIL, Nakula etc.) are under "User" in my fontbook. Even if that were a reason for this failure, "Devanagari MT", installed under "All Fonts" doesn't work.

Comment: But it did work in your first example. So why should xelatex no longer find your font?

Comment: Beats me. My first example was processed with texlive-2015 and although xelatex succeeded, the pdf had a bunch of ???? in it. Now I'm running texlive-2016 and probably have a setup issue :(

Answer (score 1):

(This is just "could not reproduce", but too long for a comment.) I installed [Nakula from its website](http://bombay.indology.info/software/fonts/devanagari/) and ran exactly the file in the question

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Nakula}
नमस्ते रुद्र मन्यवे
\end{document}
```

through `xelatex` (on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5, texlive-2015) and got the expected output:

[image: screenshot from PDF in Preview]

So I imagine it's something odd about your installation of Nakula that makes XeLaTeX not find it properly.

Comment: I can probably find a mac running a different version of OSX and check if xelatex works in that environment.

Comment: @linuxfan Also I strongly suggest uninstalling Nakula and trying with a fresh install from the website as above.

Comment: I already did a reinstall but it has no impact on the result.